# Symfony2: dynamic render parts of form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I come from these tutorials: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

I would like to have a form divided between some parts, which each of this parts contains some elements, for example:
part1: text input
part2: text area
part3: email text input.

Now I would like to render page, which contains 3 buttons or linksm which each of them dynamicly add one of elements, and these elements can be added more than one.

At the end, at the bottom will be submit button, which post form to server.

Is it possible to do this?